# Integrating Microsoft Dynamics on iOS App

Tags: ios, microsoft-dynamics

I've been looking for ages about how to integrate Microsoft Dynamics on iOS App but I can't find any reliable resources. Is there any support on iOS for Microsoft Dynamics? Can I get some advice and suggested links from you experts? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the SDK is out of the question... I would look into the CRMRestKit to use the ODATA endpoint. https://crmrestkit.codeplex.com/ or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx